# Music "database" with 3 classes; how to store information in SongDatabase class

Tags: java, class, object

Note - **no arrays are allowed to be used.**

I am new to programming & am having trouble storing my information about 4 song objects in a SongDatabase class within Java.

Basically, I have 3 classes at the moment...

Song. java with private variables...
- name
- artist
- fileSize
- duration
// These all have getters and setters.

SongDatabase.java with private variables...
- song1, song2, song3, song4 // All the Song objects stored in the system.

Interface.java
- database // variable which stores a SongDatabase object which contains all 4 songs.

Say I've prompted user to enter information on a song.

song1.setName(name); won't work as it is calling a method it doesn't have access to (inside Song class). Basically, my question is should I be calling a method from inside SongDatabase which calls the getters and setters inside Song.java to store a name?

I'm confused because I'm used to only working with 2 classes so far.

Comment: This sounds like you should be using an array/List...

Comment: I am not allowed to use arrays at all. There will only ever be 4 songs in the SongDatabase for now.

Comment: Are you allowed to use any datastructures (lists, dictionaries etc.)?

Comment: No, this is part of a challenge problem & we haven't learned those as of yet. Loops (for, do-while, while) were the last topic covered before this challenge was given.

Comment: Where are you prompting for information and where do you try to call `song1.setName(name)`?

Comment: From the Interface class. The input is collected there & the output is also shown there. Also, when I say loops were covered last; basics on 2 classes were also "covered" to understand that objects / methods can be created.

Comment: And where do you call `song1.setName(name)`?

Comment: Interface, where song1 isn't "allowed" to exist.

Comment: Well, this is what happens when a problem is given to you in such a vague manner... only to be given more vague restrictions on top of it. I've determined that you simply create all Song objects (4 of them) when you create the database object of type SongDatabase in Interface. From there; you send information to SongDatabase & then you should call methods to set / call Song object fields / data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create the song in your interface class and then set it in your database class. For example,

in interface class:

```
Song tempSong = new Song();
tempSong.setName(name);
...    
songDatabase.saveSong(tempSong);
```

To do this the getters and setters for the Song and SongDatabase classes will be public. The song1 variable doesn't exist in the interface class, just a Song object used to store the information entered by the user. You then pass this song into the database class to be stored in whichever of the songX variables is required.

Hope I've not missed something in your question...

Comment: Trust me, I would never do it this way, but it's been provided this way. I am going over it now to check.

Comment: Actually this is a fairly typical way of doing this. By not directly accessing the song variables in the song database class from other classes you are hiding the details of the database class implementation. This means that if your database class changes (eg to connect to a real database) you won't have to change any of the classes that use it. So in this case saveSong() will just save the song passed in into one of the variables whereas another implementation may save the song in the database, but the interface class will call it in exactly the same way.

Comment: I'm going to check with the person who set this because I'm still not entirely certain what is and isn't allowed to occur given the restrictions I've already relayed. Thanks for the input.

Comment: No problem, hope it goes well

Comment: When I said I would never do it this way; I mean I would never create a Song object in Interface & then pass it along. I worked it out. I only wanted to use the database variable / object of SongDatabase.